# Do these bit settings all mean the same?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, bit

```
ADMUX  = ADMUX | _BV(REFS);  // uncompounded bitwise OR
ADMUX |= _BV(REFS0);         // #define _BV(bit) (1 << (bit))
ADMUX |= bit(REFS0);         // #define bit(b) (1UL << (b))
bitSet(ADMUX, REFS0);        // #define bitSet(value, bit) ((value) |= (1UL << (bit)))
sbi(ADMUX, REFS0);           // deprecated assembly? 
ADMUX |= (1 << REFS0);       // shift operator
ADMUX |= (1 << 7);           // bit 7 is named REFS0
ADMUX |= 0b10000000;         // bin
ADMUX |= 0x80;               // hex
ADMUX |= 128;                // dec
```

*under normal 8 bit Arduino circumstances?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139514/discussion-on-question-by-gaai-do-these-bit-settings-all-mean-the-same).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already got an answer in the comments but, just to make double sure,
I tried compiling all these statements for an Uno, and they got all
translated into the *exact same machine code*. Well, almost: I had to do
some minor adjustments, which I believe are unrelated to the essence of
your question. Just for completeness, I changed the following:

1. I replaced REFS0 by REFS1: on an Uno, REFS0 is bit 6, and REFS1
   is bit 7.
2. I replaced REFS by REFS1, as the former is not defined.
3. I #included `<compat/deprecated.h>`, otherwise I get the error
   “'`sbi`' was not declared in this scope”.